# REST API: HTTP Status code for auth violation

Tags: http, rest

I'm implementing a REST API and the auth module is based on JWT. Here below are the HTTP status codes I've defined for it:

- Request without auth token: 401 UNAUTHORIZED
- Auth token expired: 410 UNAUTHORIZED
- Auth token does not contain required claims: 403 FORBIDDEN
- Auth violated (i.e. token was tampered): ???

In case of token tampering, what HTTP status code should I use? 401 (UNAUTHORIZED or 417 (EXPECTATION_FAILED)?

Answer (score 3):

How can you tell if the token was tampered with? It seems to me that you can only know if it's correct or incorrect. Somebody trying to use an invalid token would seem to me to be `UNAUTHORIZED`. `EXPECTATION`_FAILED refers specifically to the `Expect` header, which doesn't seem appropriate here.

Comment: The JWT is put on the headers and it is signed with a secret key. If the signature does not much, then it means the token was somehow tampered.